# How to get bounds after MapboxGeocoder flyto event?

Tags: geocoding, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Looks like if I call map.getBounds inside geocoder I always get the previous results.
Is there a callback or something to get the bounds after geocode flies to the destinations. Here is my code:

```
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken});
geocoder.on('result', function(ev) {

        console.log("CENTER:",ev.result.center);
        console.log("BOUNDS:",map.getBounds());
        //loadByBounds(map.getBounds());
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can react to the `mooveend` event by applying an event listener.

`"Mooveend: Fired just after the map completes a transition from one view to another, as the result of either user interaction or methods such as Map#jumpTo."`

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:moveend

Comment: Thanks, but how to apply it only once and only to geocoder, but not to all map  Mooveend events?

Comment: Hm good question. Maybe you can add a flag that you will set when the geocoder got the results. Also `map.once` will prevent the listener to fire multiple times. I made a quick jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andi_lo/cbfsnanw/